# Batching at most 10 at a time over input

Tags: loops, go

I'm trying and failing to accomplish the simple task of batching over input, at most 10 at a time. The follow code almost works:

```
func batchMe(input []int) {
    fmt.Println("Length", len(input), len(input)/10)
    for i := 0; i <= len(input)/10; i++ {
        from := i * 10
        to := (i + 1) * 10
        if len(input) < to {
            to = len(input)
        }
        fmt.Println("Batch", i, input[from:to])
    }
```

But you can see from https://play.golang.org/p/_UgFD1iDyse that it prints:

```
Length 10 1
Batch 0 [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
Batch 1 []
```

I don't want it to print Batch 1 in the case of 10 elements!

Perhaps there is a code simplification here?

Comment: instead of dividing your input into 10 buckets, just increment your counter by 10 instead of 1 then gulp that and repeat

Comment: Are you sure about the stopping condition of that first `for` loop?

Answer (score -1):

Elegant solution from Tv on #go-nuts looks like:

```
for len(input) > 0 {
    n := 10
    if n > len(input) {
        n = len(input)
    }
    chunk := input[:n]
    input = input[n:]
    fmt.Println("Batch", chunk)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Y3U8dUD7Zrr